# Type annotation in a pattern match in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm digging into Rust, specifically into gracefully handling errors, but I'm having a little trouble with type inference.

```
extern crate mysql;

use mysql as my;

fn main() {
    my_test();
}

fn my_test() -> Result<(), my::Error> {
    let pool = try!(my::Pool::new(""));
    let res = try!(pool.prep_exec("select 1 as count", ()));
    for rows in res {
        let row: my::Row = try!(rows);
        match row.take("count") {
            None => (),
            Some(i) => println!("{:?}", i),
        };
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

which leads to

> src/bin/main.rs:86:12: 86:13 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]

Unfortunately the docs in that crate use `unwrap` a lot, which does not help me. In Haskell, I would do something like `println!("{:?}", i :: i32)`, but I can't figure out how to do it in Rust. I've tried various ways to cast `row.take`, but I've haven't had any luck. I'd love to see a variety of ways in which I could have structured this code, if there is a more idiomatic way of going about it.

Comment: Note that this is only a problem because you are using `println!`, which takes a wide range of values. If you were to use the `i` value in some context that constrained the type (like by passing it to a function), then the type could be inferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at [`Row::take`](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/struct.Row.html#method.take) documentation we can see two types parameter `T` and `I`. The type `I` is inferred from the `"count"` argument, the type `T` is used for the return type. We have two options to specify the return type, [explicit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#generic-functions) in the method call, or implicit in type of a variable (like you did with `row`):

```
fn my_test() -> Result<(), my::Error> {
    let pool = try!(my::Pool::new(""));
    let res = try!(pool.prep_exec("select 1 as count", ()));
    for rows in res {
        let mut row: my::Row = try!(rows);
        // specify type T explicitly, let type I to be inferred
        match row.take::<i32, _>("count") {
            None => (),
            Some(i) => println!("{:?}", i),
        };
        // or
        let s: Option<i32> = row.take("count");
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The [type ascription RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0803-type-ascription.md) proposes a syntax (similar to the Haskell example) for annotating a sub-expression with a type.

Answer (score 3):

The types can be annotated on the `Option<T>` or `Result<T, E>` variants in the match pattern.

For Option,

```
match row.take("count") {
    None => (),
    Some::<i32>(i) => println!("{:?}", i),
}
```

Or if your function returns a Result,

```
match row.take("count") {
    Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
    Ok::<i32, _>(i) => println!("{:?}", i),
}
```