# How to I explicitly assign a type to an `Option<usize>` that is used in a `match`?

Tags: rust

I'm making a (probably bad) sorting algorithm as a practice experiment.

I'm trying to take an unsorted list of `i32` with duplicates, break it out into an array of sorted arrays (of various sizes) which I can then efficiently recombine into a single fully sorted array.  The recombination isn't implemented yet.

```
mod sort {
    use std::collections::VecDeque;

    pub fn sort_i32(unsorted_list: &Vec<i32>) { // -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut sorting = Vec::with_capacity(unsorted_list.len());
        let mut sorting_index = None;
        // let mut index: usize = 0;
        for number in unsorted_list {
            match sorting_index { // sorting_index: Option<usize>
                Some(index) => { // index: usize // index<usize>
                    // let index: usize = index as usize;
                    if number >= sorting[index].front() {
                        sorting[index].push_front(number);
                    } else if number <= sorting[index].back() {
                        sorting[index].push_back(number);
                    } else {
                        let index = index + 1; //index: usize
                        sorting_index = Some(index);
                        sorting[index] = VecDeque::with_capacity(unsorted_list.len());
                        sorting[index].push_front(number);
                    }
                }
                None => {
                    // have to initialize here because we need the first `number` to do so
                    let index = 0; //index: usize
                    sorting_index = Some(index);
                    sorting[index] = VecDeque::with_capacity(unsorted_list.len());
                    sorting[index].push_front(number);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need to explicitly tell the compiler that `index` will be `usize` as it's going to be an index into a vector:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:12:34
   |
12 |                     if number >= sorting[index].front() {
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
```

Normal typing syntax doesn't seem to work; as you can see from the comments I've tried a few approaches already.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Note, this is similar to the following post, but the critical difference is the explicit type annotation for method calls doesn't work for variables,  and I've tried to extrapolate from other places using the `var: Type` form but that doesn't seem to work in this case.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755975/type-annotation-in-a-pattern-match-in-rust

Comment: the question is either: how to I explicitly type `index` in this case since normal typing syntax doesn't work (as you can see from the comments I've tried a few approaches already), OR if explicitly typing `index` isn't the problem then what's the compiler actually complaining about?

Comment: Tangentially: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-or)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize &[T] would coerce an &Vec, I'll look into adapting these in the future

Comment: Your updated title makes no sense. If you had an `Option<usize>`, you **wouldn't need to give it a type** — that's the entire problem!

Comment: then what does this mean? `let mut sorting_index: Option<usize> = None;` if that doesn't mean it's an Option<usize> then I'm really confused.  Just because it's using the None version of that enum doesn't mean it's not still Option<usize> type, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to type `sorting` and `sorting_index`:

```
let mut sorting: Vec<VecDeque<i32>> = Vec::with_capacity(unsorted_list.len());
let mut sorting_index: Option<usize> = None;
```

That will lead to a number of adjustments and decisions at various sites in the code where  `sorting[index]` is accessed. I can add more, but after that it's mostly a matter of working through the compiler errors and making decisions on how you want to handle those cases in your algorithm.

Comment: This seems correct so I'll go ahead and select it now.  Very concise and ty for letting me figure out the rest of the refactor

Comment: Just confirming this is indeed correct.  I had to add some unwraps and *deferences but it's working now

Comment: Good! FWIW the compiler is a little unclear as to why it's not able to determine the type (e.g. with just the sorting type defined and not the sorting_index). So there's a little institutional leap from just the first line to the second. I'm poking around a bit with that because the direct error doesn't seem to point to the right cause.

Comment: The compiler doesn't *guess* what type might work. It has to *deduce* types from explicit type annotations and usage. It can be pretty clever, but at the end of the day there has to be a function or struct or something that requires a certain type, so that it can reason from there. The only exception is that numeric types default to `i32` when possible -- but you can't index a `Vec` with an `i32`, so that fallback doesn't work for `sorting_index`.

Comment: Oh agreed, but the error as of rustc 1.27.2 when sorting_index is left to be deduced seems ambiguous `cannot infer type for '_'` pointing to `sorting[index]`. It seems like the error should say `cannot infer type for 'index'` or maybe `source_index`

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. That error message could definitely use some improvement.

Comment: As far as error message improvement goes, i would have caught it a lot sooner if it complained about `sorting_index` rather than just `index` since that's what I had to explicitly type